# Number of possibilities of permutation with repetitions with additional equal elements added

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a permutation without repetition with the length $n$. The number of possibilities therefore is $n!$.

Here comes the tricky part: Now I add $m$ equal elements to this permutation (all elements must be added and the elements are not included in the permutation from before). Here are some examples with $n=3$ and $m=2$ to clarify what I mean:

$x2x13$

$xx132$

$23xx1$

$123xx$

The question now is, how many possibilities do I have now?
The result i came up with is: 
$$n! \sum_{k = 1}^{\min(m, n + 1)} \binom{n + 1}{k}\binom{m - 1}{k}$$

In words: The $n!$ possibilities from the permutation multiplied by the number of possibilities of inserting the equal elements into the permutation.

($k$ means the number of different positions the equal elements are inserted. I.e. $k=1 \rightarrow$ all $m$ elements inserted in one position; $k=2 \rightarrow$ all $m$ elements inserted in two different positions; ...)

If you assume, that $m \leq (n + 1)$ is always true, the formula from above can be simplified:
$$\frac{(m + n)!}{m!}$$

My questions now are:

- Can anyone confirm this result? I don't know how to prove this. (I
  just tried it for some smaller numbers which worked.)
- Do you know of any "simpler" way of solving this?

I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting $n+m$ spots there are $\binom{n+m}{m}$ ways to place the $m$ equal elements.

Then you fill up the remaining spots with one of the $n!$ permutations.

That gives: $$\binom{n+m}{m}n!=\frac{(n+m)!}{m!}$$ possibilities.

Comment: brilliant. Thanks for this alternative (and much easier way) of thinking about it!

Comment: You are very welcome